# Azure Blob list keys JsonSerializer.Deserialize returning null C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a very simple deserialization to be made. Basically all I do is to retrieve the following json and deserialize as `StorageAccountListKeysResult` of `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models`:

```
{\"creationTime\":\"2021-12-17T12:26:19.5708372Z\",\"keyName\":\"key1\",\"value\":\"qzyyzfNe1bkhBeOVYNXiQ6BjVlDnLsnDWhVqhTrD6whPE78kf/1A/jNeQsUjMvQVnl3dtdKxZmsuMjlx3ru7Q==\",\"permissions\":\"FULL\"},{\"creationTime\":\"2021-12-17T12:26:19.5708372Z\",\"keyName\":\"key2\",\"value\":\"t+4ao7yMyWvqoiSjrNCH5gPtDC7+Qnow2SdPoFXzOXkPyBrOex/BVUPXtGFW78XAXrQ7ITDZnC8RIyXe5jVaQ==\",\"permissions\":\"FULL\"}
```

I doubled checked the json result several times and compared with the model and it seems all fine to me but I get `null` as result from deserialization.

Here is the code:

```cs
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
};

var json = "{\"Keys\":[{\"creationTime\":\"2021-12-17T12:26:19.5708372Z\",\"keyName\":\"key1\",\"value\":\"qzyyzfNe1bkhBeOVYNXiQ6BjVlDnLsnDWhVqhTrD6whPE78kf/1A/jNeQsUjMvQVnl3dtdKxZmsuMjlx3ru7Q==\",\"permissions\":\"FULL\"},{\"creationTime\":\"2021-12-17T12:26:19.5708372Z\",\"keyName\":\"key2\",\"value\":\"t+4a7oyMyWvqoiSjrNCH5gPtDC7+Qnow2SdPoFXzOXkPyBrOex/BVUPXtGFW78XAXrQ7ITDZnC8RIyXe5jVaQ==\",\"permissions\":\"FULL\"}]}";
var listKeys = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StorageAccountListKeysResult>(json, serializerOptions); // returns null
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the properties of `StorageAccountListKeysResult` have no setters.

Comment: To be clear: `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` doesn't return null.  It returns a `StorageAccountListKeysResult` object whose `Keys` property is null.  (All the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` overloads return `object?` or `TValue?`, which indicates that null could be returned, but under what circumstances this could happen isn't documented.... and I have yet to see it in practice.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `Newtonsoft`. Microsoft uses   Newtonsoft for `StorageAccountListKeysResult`, so I guess this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing your `Keys` attribute in the JSON to `keys`. Your `json` should look like:

```
var json = "{\"keys\":[{\"creationTime\":\"2021-12-17T12:26:19.5708372Z\",\"keyName\":\"key1\",\"value\":\"qzyyzfNe1bkhBeOVYNXiQ6BjVlDnLsnDWhVqhTrD6whPE78kf/1A/jNeQsUjMvQVnl3dtdKxZmsuMjlx3ru7Q==\",\"permissions\":\"FULL\"},{\"creationTime\":\"2021-12-17T12:26:19.5708372Z\",\"keyName\":\"key2\",\"value\":\"t+4a7oyMyWvqoiSjrNCH5gPtDC7+Qnow2SdPoFXzOXkPyBrOex/BVUPXtGFW78XAXrQ7ITDZnC8RIyXe5jVaQ==\",\"permissions\":\"FULL\"}]}";
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage.models.storageaccountlistkeysresult.keys?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Storage_Models_StorageAccountListKeysResult_Keys

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="keys")]
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountKey> Keys { get; }
```

Comment: Why should I do that? I'm passing `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true`. If I would have to do string replacement I would rather try another approach. This json result comes from the azure API, I didn't create it myself.

Comment: I have not tried running the code (so I may be wrong). I just looked at the documentation and the expected property name value was `keys` and not `Keys`. On that basis I provided the answer.